# In MVC method for controller is not called from inside of the Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, kendo-grid, editortemplates

I need to initialize `Kendo.ComboBox` inside of the `Editor Template`.
I have defined the template as follows:

```
<script>
    function GetReportID() {
        return {
            reportID: 8
        }
    }
</script>

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                    .DataValueField("ReportPropertyID")
                    .DataTextField("PropertyName")
                    .DataSource(d => d.Read(r => r.Action("PopulateReportProperty", "TestTicketReportProperty").Data("GetReportID()"))))
```

This template is rendered inside of the `Kendo.Grid`:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.ReportPropertyData).ClientTemplate("#=ReportProperty.PropertyName#").EditorTemplateName("_PropertyNameEditor").Sortable(false).Width(180);
```

The method inside of the controller that needs to be called:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PopulateReportProperty([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int reportID)
{
    var reportProperty = TicketReportPropertyRepository.GetReportPropertyEntityRepository(reportID);
    ViewData["defaultPropertyEntity"] = reportProperty.First();
    return Json(reportProperty.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This method is not called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try HttpGet?

Answer (score 0):

Is your _PropertyNameEditor file located inside your Views>Shared>EditorTemplates folder?

Also you may need to do [UIHint("_PropertyNameEditor")] on the attribute in your ViewModel.